# BASH Substitute a line

Tags: bash, sed

How can substitute a line that matches a specific pattern with a blank line in a bash script?

For example:

```
-hello:world:this 
-is:an:example
-good:morning:
```

and then when I launch the script with the parameters `is` and `an`. The expected output is:

```
-hello:world:this:

-good:morning:
```

Comment: Use `sed` in the loop :)

Comment: if i use sed in the loop, i can't substitut the line whit a blank line :| i try with different command but nothing

Comment: What have you tried? What's input? Could you explain more your mind? show us your samples and tries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do a substitution with `sed 's/^.*is:an.*$//'`:

```
$ cat file
^[[A-hello:world:this 
-is:an:example
-good:morning:    

$ sed 's/^.*is:an.*$//' file
-hello:world:this 

-good:morning:
```

Explanation:

A substitution with sed looks like this `s/regexp/replace/` substitute any part of the line that matches the regexp and replace it with `replace`.

The regexp `^.*is:an.*$` matches any whole line that contains the string `is:an` and replaces it with nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much, but if i want substitute the line whit parameters 'is' and 'example', whit two different substrings, how can i change the expression?

Comment: Like this `sed 's/is/IS/;s/example/EXAMPLE/'` please accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Comment: I try the script, but the result it's only on the output, the file not be change. I try to redirect the output to the same file, but after it's empty... :(

Comment: You cannot redirect the output to the input file, this is called clobbering `sed` has an option to save the changes directly to the file `-i` so do `sed -i 's/is/IS/;s/example/EXAMPLE/'` for tools that don't have such an option you need to use a tmp file like `head -10 input > tmp; mv tmp input`